# Getting error in xmlhttp query but working fine with IE query

Tags: excel, xmlhttprequest

```
Sub Test(URL As Range)
    For Each cell In URL
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "https://www.kimptonhotels", vbTextCompare) Then
           Dim xml_obj As New XMLHTTP
           xml_obj.Open "GET", cell, False
           xml_obj.send

           Dim htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
           htmldoc.body.innerHTML = xml_obj.responseText   ' I am trying to get some data from [this link][1] by VBA in Excel
```

Getting error on this line:

```
xml_obj.send
```

I am getting required data which I need by creating IE object method fine.

I tried to get via xmlhttp method but I got error on `xml_obj.send`

> Error 2146697211 (800c005) The system cannot locate the resource specified

I tried searching google but couldn't find something similar.

I am asking this just out of curiosity, what is the problem and why I am getting error?

The xmlhttp code is working fine with some other https sites I checked.

Thanks

Comment: This is code which I am using and working fine on another sites but giving error on mentioned in questionSub Test(URL As Range)
For Each cell In URL
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "kimptonhotels", vbTextCompare) Then
Dim xml_obj As New XMLHTTP
xml_obj.Open "GET", cell, False
xml_obj.send

Comment: Your code uses `HTTP` while your link is a `HTTPS` link. And you have still not mentioned **what** error you get.

Comment: I am getting run time error 2146697211 (800c005) The system cannot locate the resource specified.Checked this code with other https sites and working fine.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce that error. I get a error '-2146697191 (800c0019)' which is a SSL certificate error "Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid". But this I also get with Internet Explorer.

Comment: I think that there is nothing wrong with code but something with the site as code is working on another sites. Can someone Expert point out? Cheers